# how to define YYERROR_VERBOSE in .y file

Tags: bison

I am using bison parser.

To get expected and unexpected token names in error message, variable `YYERROR_VERBOSE` need to be set in the generated y.go file. How to set it from the .y file?

Comment: I am new to this. so I am searching for how to get the clear message from the generated parser. while searching in google I saw this site
http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~bvz/teaching/cs461Sp11/notes/bison/ from this 
I get "%error-verbose" this to use in definition , but I am getting  "bad syntax in %error"  error. so I dont know where to put it in the yacc file.

Comment: Perhaps you are not using a sufficiently recent bison version. In any caso, your best bet for bison information is the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a snippet of a grammar

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdarg.h>
    #include <strings.h>
    #include "calc.h"

    int yylex(void);    
    void yyerror(char *s);
    symrec * symTable;
    /**
        temporary variable declarations
    */
    linkedList * temp_list = NULL;
    linkedList * programRoutineList = NULL;
    linkedList * argList = NULL;
    program * prg;

%}
%error-verbose

%union {
    int iValue;                 
    symrec * sRec;
    nodeType *nPtr;

    basicType basic;  
    parameter *parameter;
    routine * routine;
    linkedList *list;       
};                          

%token <iValue> INTEGER         
%token <sRec> VARIABLE
%token WHILE IF PRINT FOR TO
%nonassoc IFX
%nonassoc ELSE
…
…
```

This is the beginning of a yacc file. This, being part of a yacc source file is the declaration part where, as you can read, the user may define useful stuff of almost any kind (C compliant).

As part of the instruction you can see the `%error-verbose` directive which is interpreted by yacc as an instruction to be more "user" error friendly in signaling errors. For a more detailed view on such directive take a look at [error-verbose the bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Reporting.html) (Remember to use google: it knows a lot of stuff ;) )

For a complete example take a look at [this error tracker example](https://github.com/LorenzoGramola/LFC2014-2015/blob/master/3.1%20-%20yacc%20exercises/error_tracker.y). You need error_tracker_lexer.l and error_tracker.y to make it work. You find them in the very same directory.
Once you compile it, you can use it as my_exec < input_error_tracker…
The expected output is

```
at line 2 follows detail on columns--> 2.3-2.4: division by zero
returning 1 as default action
```

The nice thing, you can build you own file containing e.g.: 89 + ad

the output will be

```
syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting NUM or '-' or '('
```

Hope this will be helpful..